# Codeigniter 3 really slow query when Group By is called

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have this query

```
SELECT `PR_CODIGO`, `PR_EXIBIR`, `PR_NOME`, `PRC_DETALHES` FROM `PROPRIETARIOS` LEFT JOIN `PROPRIETARIOSCONTATOS` ON `PROPRIETARIOSCONTATOS`.`PRC_COD_CAD` = `PROPRIETARIOS`.`PR_CODIGO` WHERE `PR_EXIBIR` = 'T' LIMIT 20
```

It runs very fast, less than 1 second.

If i add GROUP BY, it takes several seconds (5+) to run. Even the Group By field being index.

I'm using group by because the query above returns repeated rows (i search for a name and his contacts on another table, show's 4 times same name).

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With the GROUP BY clause, the LIMIT clause isn't applied until *after* the rows are collapsed by the group by operation.

To get an understanding of the operations that MySQL is performing and which indexes are being considered and chosen by the optimizer, we use **`EXPLAIN`**.

Unstated in the question is what "field" (columns or expressions) are in the `GROUP BY` clause. So we are only guessing.

Based on the query shown in the question...

```
SELECT pr.pr_codigo
     , pr.pr_exibir
     , pr.pr_nome
     , prc.prc_detalhes
  FROM `PROPRIETARIOS` pr
  LEFT
  JOIN `PROPRIETARIOSCONTATOS` prc
    ON prc.prc_cod_cad = pr.pr_codigo
 WHERE pr.pr_exibir = 'T'
 LIMIT 20
```

Our guess at the most appropriate indexes...

```
 ... ON PROPRIETARIOSCONTATOS (prc_cod_cad, prc_detalhes)

 ... ON PROPRIETARIOS (pr_exibir, pr_codigo, pr_exibir, pr_nome)
```

Our guess is going to change depending on what column(s) are listed in the GROUP BY clause.  And we might also suggest an alternative query to return an equivalent result.

But without knowing the `GROUP BY` clause, without knowing if our guesses about which table each column is from are correct, without knowing the column datatypes, without any estimates of cardinality, and without example data and expected output, ... we're flying blind and just making guesses.

Comment: I solved without use Group By, but your answer it's a good tip to solve a future problem with group by. I'm so tired, thank you.